# Insert multiple values from one table to another using eloquent/query builder

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have the following code:

```
$users = User::where('user_id', Auth::id())->where('subject_id', 2)->get();

      $users = $users->ToArray();

      DB::table('mytable')->insert($users);
```

This works fine until when I decide to repeat the function. When I do I get an error message telling me that I can't repeat the primary key values. So my question is how do I input the same `user_id` and `subject_id` without also inputting the primary key from the `User` table (model). Basically I want to input my `user_id` and `subject_id` as a new field and not copy over the primary key? So that `mytable` looks like this:

```
ID|user_id|subject_id
1 |4      |2
2 |4      |2
```

Comment: Create a composite key using ID and user_id

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: you cannot leave the user_id empty since it is the primary key in your table. Since you wanted to repeat your user_id value in this table you can create the combination of ID and user_id as primary key making it unique then you can have repeated values user_id but this combination leads still leads to a unique index.

Comment: that is why is simply want to input the values as new values and ignoring the primary key values from my `User` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply select only the keys you want. For example:

```
$users = User::where('user_id', Auth::id())
->where('subject_id', 2)->select('user_id', 'subject_id')->get();
```